# Updated input field value not displaying in Webkit

Tags: javascript, dom, blackberry, browser, webkit

This problem has me absolutely stumped so would welcome any insights.

I am trying to create an input mask in javascript. The input must be of the format AA1111 (where A=capital letters and 1=numbers). This site is designed to be used on a Blackberry browser (OS6 Webkit).

I am triggering some javascript with the onkeyup event which will rewrite the content of the input.

```
<script>
function checkInput(x) {

    var y = document.getElementById(x).value;
    var c = y.slice(-1);
    var n = "";
    if (y.length < 3) n = c.toUpperCase();
    else if (y.length < 7) n = convertToNum(c.toUpperCase());

    document.getElementById(x).value = y.slice(0, y.length - 1) + n;
}
```

```
Input:<input  type="text" id="search" class="big" OnKeyUp="checkInput(this.id);" autofocus="true" />
```

In firefox and IE this works as expected, but on the Blackberry (and also Chrome) the input field does not **always** get updated with the correct letters and numbers.
It seems to work on first load and then stop after the first refresh.
Inspecting the DOM when it is not working shows that the .value attribute **is** updated correctly, however this doesn't get shown in the browser window.

I have set up an example here http://aspspider.info/jessop  to illustrate what I am trying to do. If you try this in a webkit browser (ideally on an OS6 Blackberry!) then hopefully you will see my problem.

Is this a bug in Webkit or something I am doing wrong?  Any ideas of a workaround?

Many thanks.

Comment: I can't test your example on a blackberry, but if I may suggest an alternate route to solve your problem, I think you should capture onkeydown (and not onkeyup), which happens before the character shows up in the input field. You should then preventDefault() on your event object and add the typed character, or converted char-to-number to the end of the input's value (no need for slicing here). As a plus, you won't get characters showing up and disappearing in your input. Also, I tested your example in chrome and it seems to work fine, indicating that webkit may not be the problem.

Comment: You also have another problem with your current code, typing really fast two characters will keep the first one, even if it shouldn't be there. Also, some letters are transformed in numbers when they should be number (letters: wersdfxc)

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, I will test that tomorrow and post back with result.  DangerMonkey - the letters transforming to numbers is to allow the user to enter the numbers on the blackberry keypad without having to use alt to get the numbers (if that makes sense!). For instance if the user enters W when a number is expected then that will transform to 1 (which shares the key on the blackberry).